# I cant save date using datepicker in my database

Tags: php, mysql

here's my phpcode :

```
error_reporting(0);
$userLog = $_SESSION['user'];

mysql_select_db("dbwebsite") or die($connect_error);

$time = time();
$event = $_POST['eventname'];
$date = $_POST['datepicker'];

if($event == "" | $date = ""){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Type your Post First!");</script>';
        header("Refresh:-0.0001;user_admin.php");
}
else{
            $insert_error = "Your text could not be posted";
            $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO events VALUES ('','$event','$date','$time')") or die ($insert_error);
            header("Location:user_admin.php");
}
?>
```

here's my datepicker code:

```
<script src="effects/calendar/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="effects/calendar/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<html>
<form action="update_event.php" name="event" id="event" method="post">
  <p style="color:#000000">Event name:<input type="text" name="eventname" id="eventname" /></p>
  <p style="color:#000000">Event Date:<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" /></p>
  <br /><input type="submit" name="btnevent" id="btnevent" value="Post event" />
  </form>
</html>
```

0000-00-00 shows up on my database instead of the date i picked using my datepicker.

Comment: What did you enter in the datefield ?

Comment: It depends on what you are using in your DB too, do you have that field set to `DATE` or `DATE AND TIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, etc.  I would suggest if you are saving the date, to use `DATE` and make sure you are formatting it like YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: This has nothing to do with phpmyadmin

Comment: Do `echo $date;` and post result here. Also post `CREATE TABLE ...` for your `events` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
first check the datepicker posted date and change the date format
mysql date format is YYYY-MM-DD
So you change your date format

<?php
$event = $_POST['eventname'];
$date = $_POST['datepicker'];
$dd=date_create($date);
$datepic=date_format($dd,"Y-m-d");

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO events VALUES ('','$event','$datepic','$time')") or die 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning value `$data = ""` to null

change  `if($event == "" | $date = ""){` to  `if($event == "" || $date == ""){`

or you can try something like isset

```
if(!isset($event) || !isset($date))
```

Comment: FYI `isset()` accepts unlimited arguments -- only one call is necessary.